# Linkify's clickable method blocks listview click method

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

Hi i have a listview with textview in every row with a text linkified with defined pattern in it , i use this small code to make linkified items can be clickable and call another activity in my app.But before that i am using imaview above the list to make navigation appear on listview , when i added

```
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    Pattern Matcher = Pattern.compile("pattern here");
    String Url = "sth://";
    Linkify.addLinks(entrySpan, Matcher, Url);
```

Instead of onClick method of listview on just linkfy clicks are working , but i have to make them work bot

Here is code that i am using for listview click method but this seems never firing after setting linkify set movement , i am switching back and forth between Vısıble and Gone after every click.

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(Entry.totalPageNumber>1){
                    //if no more than one page exist no need to navigate

                    if(show == false){
                        findViewById(R.id.back).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.forward).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.start).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.last).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        show=true;
                    }else if(show==true){
                        findViewById(R.id.back).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.forward).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.start).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.last).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        show=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How to resolve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it , just moved the onClickListener implementation into my getView method which draw textview and directly apply onClickListener to textView and finally both of them working happily

```
TextView textView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.entryRowTextView);


textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(Entry.totalPageNumber>1){
                                //if no more than one page exist no need to navigate
                                Log.d(EKSI, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                                if(show == false){
                                    findViewById(R.id.back).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    findViewById(R.id.forward).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    findViewById(R.id.start).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    findViewById(R.id.last).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    show=true;
                                }else if(show==true){
                                    findViewById(R.id.back).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    findViewById(R.id.forward).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    findViewById(R.id.start).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    findViewById(R.id.last).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    show=false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know if you add a button in a listview item then you cannot select that List item any more. You have then to use a more complicated techniques of creating a custom adapter and using getView method to control the selection with setTag and getTag for each button. This may not be easy for a beginner but it is necessary to learn.

Here is one simple example to start with: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

There is also a problem with list being recycled. This means that if there are 10 rows on the screen the 11th will show to be selected or changed too when you scroll and 21st and so on... here getView has to explicitly control the layout of each listitem by using
if(condition which determins layout){...code...}else{...code...}